# can azure storage be used to make a social APP between azure users

Tags: azure-storage

can azure storage be used to make a social APP between azure users

My friend and me want to build an social APP based on azure storage.
Can I use azure storage realise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Storage in couple of ways to implement your idea. One of them being, to store the content shared between users from the social app. You can use Blob storage to store any type of text or binary data, such as a document or media files. Or you can use Table storage to store data as key-value pairs. 
The other way is using the Queue storage for implementing a reliable messaging for workflow processing and for communication between components of your app in a cloud service.
Here are some resources you will find useful to design your app:

Azure Storage Samples: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-samples/ 
Get Started with Azure Storage in 5mins: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-getting-started-guide/